# XSLT analyze string and tokenazation proper usage

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I'm trying to analyze some huge string and I'm using two different methods in XSLT (one called tokenize and the other one called analyze string).

Suppose I have the following string:

```
    var ActivitiesData = 
[{"method": {"name": "Bras", "val": "Vegas"}, 
"laundry": "-<a href=\"http://www.site.com\" target=\"_blank\">OnCase</a>:   #9", 
"XSD": "true", 
"stages": [{"name": "on_site", "DB": "12", "OVL": true, "RVT: "BGD"}, {"name": "on_site", "DB": "12", "OVL": true, "RVT": true}], 
"NationalUsage": "Degree", 
"Overlay": 32, 
"Build_Tick": "12", 
"Mozilla": {"Cloud": "Visual", "Decrease": "10"}, 
"updates": "XXX", 
}]
```

my issue raises as I'm trying to create items of each data. My REGEX is the following, (.,',\s+"') - which means that each time a , ' is being match I can differentiate between one data to another.

BUT,

in the stages data I also have these string (, ') and therefore I'm creating them as individual items while I want to create them as childs of stages - creating a special item element called <stage-itmes>.

That is, only when I see data which starts with the following chars "[{" (like in stages) I want somehow to reformat the text (. ') to something else so in the future when I'll be using this tokenize string(, ') these string won't match.

I hope I was able to expalin myself clearly, I might be using the wrong method to do it. The final result I want to get is :

```
    <item>
    "method": {"name": "Bras", "val": "Vegas"}, 
</item>
<item>
    "laundry": "-<a href=\"http://www.site.com\" target=\"_blank\">OnCase</a>:   #9", 
</item>
<item>
    "XSD": "true", 
</item>
<item>
    "stages": [{"name": "on_site", "DB": "12", "OVL": true, "RVT: "BGD"}, {"name": "on_site", "DB": "12", "OVL": true, "RVT": true}], 
</item>


..and so on..
```

That is the analyze string I have used while trying to catch these stages data in order to replace the string (, ') to something unique which later on won't be caught in my tokenize and will be creating individual elements:

```
<xsl:variable name="pTokenize">    



<xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space($activitiesDataText)" regex="(&quot;stages&quot;:[^\]]*)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(1), ', &apos;', ',-&apos;')"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>

</xsl:variable>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can find [here](http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2007/07/05/transforming-json/) a parser written completely in XSLT 2.0 for the JSON grammar as described in json.org** -- this isn't the full or official JSON grammar, so the parser may or maynot work with your data -- just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You've given an example string, but you haven't shown us its grammar. It looks very like JSON, and if that's the case then it's a recursive grammar rather than a regular grammar, which means that it can't be parsed using a regular expression.

There are plenty of utilities that will convert JSON to XML, including ones that you can invoke from XSLT (Saxon has a parse-json extension function). Or you can write your own parser: Dimitre Novatchev has examples of complex parsers written in XSLT, and Gunther Rademacher publishes REX, a tool for generating parsers from an XML description of the grammar.

I rather suspect since you are trying to do this the wrong way that you are rather new to parsing, in which case I would recommend reading up on the subject before going much further.